# why do interdepedent functions across modules evaluate to undefined at runtime in node javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error

I have three javascript files

`moduleA.js`, `moduleB.js`, and `index.js`

**moduleA.js**

```
const {b1} = require('./moduleB');
const a1 = ()=>{
    console.log('a1 called')
};
const a2 = ()=>{
    console.log('a2 called');
    b1()
};

module.exports = {a1, a2};
```

**moduleB.js**

```
const {a1} = require('./moduleA');

const b1 = () => {
    console.log('b1 called');
    a1();
};
const b2 = () => {
    console.log('b2 called');
};

module.exports = {b1, b2};
```

**index.js**

```
const {a2} = require('./moduleA');
a2();
```

How come invoking `a2()` throws an error at runtime because `a2` is `undefined` in node? I've not seen this type of error in another language such as Java.

Is there a solution to this apart from putting `a2` in another file such as `moduleC.js` and call `moduleC.a2()`?

[example code on codingrooms](https://app.codingrooms.com/w/Kz7LAKSsr3ur)

**The current output is:**

```
TypeError: a1 is not a function
    at b1 (... /moduleB.js:5:5)
    at a2 (... /moduleA.js:7:5)
```

**Expected output is**

```
// a2 called
// b1 called
// a1 called
```

**Additional information**

Based on the accepted answer provided by Felix and my understanding of the *Modules* chapter in Matt Frisbie's *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*. I drew this graph to assist my understanding of the module loading process in CommonJS. I hope whoever stumbles upon this question in the future will find it helpful as much as I did.

[image: module loading with circular dependency]

Comment: The error message is _“`TypeError`: `a1` is not a function”_, not `a2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the error is that **`a1`** is `undefined`, not `a2`. The reason for that is that you have a circular dependency between module A and module B.

At the time module B imports `a1` from module A, module A's `exports` object is still empty, i.e. `a1` doesn't exist yet.

To fix this you need to do two things:

- Delay ccessing `a1` until it's needed (which is after all modules are evaluated).
- Do not overwrite the initial exports object but update it instead.

```
const a = require('./moduleA');
//   ^^^ 

const b1 = () => {
    console.log('b1 called');
    a.a1();
//  ^^
};
const b2 = () => {
    console.log('b2 called');
};

module.exports = {b1, b2};
```

```
const {b1} = require('./moduleB');
exports.a1 = ()=>{
    console.log('a1 called')
};
exports.a2 = ()=>{
    console.log('a2 called');
    b1()
};
```

Or of course refactor your code so that it doesn't use circular dependencies.

Comment: It doesn't work. See https://app.codingrooms.com/w/ufav6MRGK4oU

Comment: Ugh, right because you are overwriting the exports object. I forgot (haven't worked with CommonJS in a while). I'll update the answer... updated.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I added the module dependency graph based on your comments and my understanding from reading the Modules chapter in Matt Frisbie's Professional JavaScript for Web Developers. Could you please comment on it and point out errors if you spot any?